# Rails error while migrating to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, database-migration, production-environment

when I try to migrate to heroku by heroku run rake
I get the following error:

```
Running rake on ⬢ friends-clique... up, run.8185
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha3/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::VERSION
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:2: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha3/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::BOOTSTRAP_SHA
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:3: warning: previous definition of BOOTSTRAP_SHA was here
DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly. (called from block in <top (required)> at /app/config/environments/production.rb:82)
Abort testing: Your Rails environment is running in production mode!
```

I thought heroku runs in production mode , What just happened?

Comment: have you run project locally on production mode?

Comment: You have gem conflicts with Bootstrap, check yr gemfile, also, try `heroku run bundle install`

Comment: What is the exact command you are running?

Comment: What does your heroku logs say?

Comment: What is your `RACK_ENV` and `RAILS_ENV` on heroku ? You can get this by running `heroku config`.

Answer (score 0):

The right command to migrate your database with heroku is

```
Heroku run rake db:migrate
```

This should run fine.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can follow this guide to solve youse issue [official asset configuration for heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline)